# is ArrayDescriptor threadsafe?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, thread-safety

Is an instance of oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor threadsafe ?

The API http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/ArrayDescriptor.html for this class does not mention anything about thread safety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `javap` command on `oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor` class .. It can be observed that none of the public methods of `oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor` class is synchronized. Here is what javap tells:

```
E:\users>javap oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor
Compiled from "ArrayDescriptor.java"
public class oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor extends oracle.sql.TypeDescriptor implem
ents java.io.Serializable{
    public static final int TYPE_VARRAY;
    public static final int TYPE_NESTED_TABLE;
    public static final int CACHE_NONE;
    public static final int CACHE_ALL;
    public static final int CACHE_LAST;
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    public static final boolean TRACE;
    public static final boolean PRIVATE_TRACE;
    public static final java.lang.String BUILD_DATE;
    public static oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor createDescriptor(java.lang.String, java.sql.Connection) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public static oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor createDescriptor(java.lang.String, java.sql.Connection, boolean, boolean) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public static oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor createDescriptor(oracle.sql.SQLName,  java.sql.Connection) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public static oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor createDescriptor(oracle.sql.SQLName, java.sql.Connection, boolean, boolean) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public static oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor createDescriptor(oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeCOLLECTION) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor(java.lang.String, java.sql.Connection) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor(oracle.sql.SQLName, java.sql.Connection) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor(oracle.sql.SQLName, oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeCOLLECTION, java.sql.Connection) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor(oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeCOLLECTION, java.sql.Connection) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    static oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor createDescriptor(oracle.sql.SQLName, byte[], int, byte[], byte[], oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection, byte[]) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public int getBaseType() throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public java.lang.String getBaseName() throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeCOLLECTION getOracleTypeCOLLECTION();
    public int getArrayType() throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public long getMaxLength() throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public java.lang.String descType()  throws java.sql.SQLException;
    java.lang.String descType(java.lang.StringBuffer, int) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    int toLength(oracle.sql.ARRAY) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    byte[] toBytes(oracle.sql.ARRAY, boolean) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    oracle.sql.Datum[] toOracleArray(oracle.sql.ARRAY, long, int, boolean) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    java.lang.Object[] toJavaArray(oracle.sql.ARRAY, long, int, java.util.Map, boolean) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public java.sql.ResultSet toResultSet(oracle.sql.ARRAY, long, int, java.util.Map, boolean) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public java.sql.ResultSet toResultSet(oracle.sql.Datum[], long, int, java.util.Map) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public java.sql.ResultSet toResultSetFromLocator(byte[], long, int, java.util.Map) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public java.sql.ResultSet toResultSetFromImage(oracle.sql.ARRAY, long, int, java.util.Map) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public static java.lang.Object[] makeJavaArray(int, int) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    oracle.sql.Datum[] toOracleArray(java.lang.Object, long, int) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    java.lang.Object toNumericArray(oracle.sql.ARRAY, long, int, int, boolean) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public int getTypeCode() throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public byte[] toBytes(oracle.sql.Datum[]) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public byte[] toBytes(java.lang.Object[]) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public int length(byte[]) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public oracle.sql.Datum[] toArray(byte[]) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public oracle.sql.Datum[] toArray(java.lang.Object) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public java.sql.ResultSet toResultSet(byte[], java.util.Map) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public java.sql.ResultSet toResultSet(byte[], long, int, java.util.Map) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public static int getCacheStyle(oracle.sql.ARRAY) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    static {};
}
```

Hence you should carry on with this class assuming that it is not thread-safe.

**UPDATE**
As per your claim since all the private and public variables of the class are final so there is no way that the internal state of the instance would get changed by its method. But `oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor` also inherits `oracle.sql.TypeDescriptor` which contains non-final variables as shown below:

```
E:\users>javap -private oracle.sql.TypeDescriptor
Compiled from "TypeDescriptor.java"
public abstract class oracle.sql.TypeDescriptor extends java.lang.Object implements java.io.Serializable{
    public static boolean DEBUG_SERIALIZATION;
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    oracle.sql.SQLName sqlName;
    oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleNamedType pickler;
    transient oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection connection;
    private static final java.lang.String _Copyright_2004_Oracle_All_Rights_Reserved_;
    public static final boolean TRACE;
    public static final boolean PRIVATE_TRACE;
    public static final java.lang.String BUILD_DATE;
    protected oracle.sql.TypeDescriptor();
    protected oracle.sql.TypeDescriptor(java.lang.String, java.sql.Connection)throws java.sql.SQLException;
    protected oracle.sql.TypeDescriptor(oracle.sql.SQLName, java.sql.Connection)throws java.sql.SQLException;
    protected oracle.sql.TypeDescriptor(oracle.sql.SQLName, oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT, java.sql.Connection)throws java.sql.SQLException;
    protected oracle.sql.TypeDescriptor(oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT, java.sql.Connection)throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public synchronized java.lang.String getName() throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public synchronized oracle.sql.SQLName getSQLName() throws java.sql.SQLException;
    void initSQLName()       throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public java.lang.String getSchemaName()       throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public java.lang.String getTypeName()       throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleNamedType getPickler();
    public oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection getInternalConnection();
    public void setPhysicalConnectionOf(java.sql.Connection);
    public abstract int getTypeCode()       throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public static oracle.sql.TypeDescriptor getTypeDescriptor(java.lang.String,oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public static oracle.sql.TypeDescriptor getTypeDescriptor(java.lang.String,oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection, byte[], long) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public boolean isInHierarchyOf(java.lang.String) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream)throws java.io.IOException;
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream)throws java.io.IOException, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException;
    public void setConnection(java.sql.Connection) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public static java.lang.String getSubtypeName(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection,byte[], long) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public void initMetadataRecursively()       throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public void initNamesRecursively()       throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public void fixupConnection(oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public java.lang.String toXMLString()       throws java.sql.SQLException;
    public void printXML(java.io.PrintStream)       throws java.sql.SQLException;
    void printXML(java.io.PrintWriter, int)       throws java.sql.SQLException;
    void printXMLHeader(java.io.PrintWriter)       throws java.sql.SQLException;
    static {};
}
```

Hence there are the possibilities that these non-final variables would changed unpredictably by various threads accessing the same object of `oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor` class. So I still think that it is not `Thread-safe`.

Comment: Thanks for the post. However, it is not necessary for the methods of a class to be synchronized in order for a instance of that class to be thread safe. For instance if the methods do not affect the internal state of a class instance, they do not need to be synchronized. None of the methods out here seem to be modifying the state of the instance variables, so it is quite likely that the class is thread-safe.

Comment: I agree with your first point .. How can you be so sure that the methods are not modifying the internal state of instance variable?

Comment: @user2200690: of course all the instance variables of `ArrayDescriptor` are final including private one also.. But its superclass(`oracle.sql.TypeDescriptor`) instance variables are not final. So it might be possible that these variables states might get changed unpredictably.

Comment: I agree with your analysis above. Looks like it not thread safe after all.

Comment: @user2200690: So you are assured now that it is not safe to use it assuming it to be thread-safe?

Answer (score 1):

Guess what?  The source code doesn't appear to be available in the normal places one would find it, so there's no way of knowing for sure ... apart from asking Oracle support.

Based on the API design, it *could* be thread safe.  There are no setters, and it looks like the class is intended to be immutable from the perspective of the client.  You may be able to confirm this by pointing `javap` at the bytecode file and seeing if the instance variables are all declared as `final`.

However, if you can't get confirmation, the safe approach is to assume that the class is not thread-safe.

Comment: Based on the post below, it seems like all the instance variables are declared as final. I'll try to get an answer for this question from Oracle support.